# R: How to efficiently save numbers between 0 and 1 as bytes in a file

Tags: arrays, r, byte

In R I have n numbers `x_1`, ... ,`x_n` between 0 and 1 and want to save them compressed lossy such that each number only takes one byte:

- For `k` in {1,...,n} round each `x_k` to the next number of the form `i_k*1/255`, where `i_k` is in the set {1,...,255}
- Then I want to save the n numbers `i_1`, ... ,`i_n` as bytes in a file.

This will result in a file with a size of n bytes. The reverse operation of retrieving the approximations of `x_1`, ... ,`x_n` again from the file is also of interest to me.

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Why do you want to save it as bytes?

Comment: @Christoph Actually I want to implement a simple image compression method using reduced SVD as an example for my PCA thesis. This is a matrix decomposition of the image matrix X as X=U S V and by scaling S I achieve that the cols of U and the rows of V are in [-1,1]. Then I want to discretize them before saving U, the diagonal of S and V. Without doing so one cannot achieve a high compression rate. Of course it is worse than jpeg but one can achieve a factor of 0.1 in size compared to bmp and and there are still some details visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To compress

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(1024*400)
y=as.raw(255*x)
save(y, file="test.raw")
```

Creates a file of 401kb on my operating system for storing 400kb - I assume that there's a slight overhead related to storing the size of the file.

## To decompress

```
rm(y)
load("test.raw")
rbind(x=head(x),y=head(as.numeric(y)/255))
#       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#x 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
#y 0.8941176 0.2627451 0.3686275 0.5725490 0.9058824 0.2000000
```

As you'd expect, there's a loss of accuracy at the third decimal place due to the storage restrictions